# Rails: Autocomplete / Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do you know a gem or an easy way to search records in the DB and use the output for a Rails form? I have quite large Dropdowns and this would be an easy way to minimize the time to search the right value inside the dropdown. Thank you guys!

Comment: I may say your question is too broad, but then, the heading justifies. If I get you well, you are trying to get an autocomplete feature for a field in your form. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jquery-ui-rails gem](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails), according to this [rails-cast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms).  It will work well for you.

You can also [find it here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7yhPlIehFA)

Comment: Any other more recent alternatives ? jquery-ui is such a big big gun for something so common as autocompletion... And the Railscast episode you linked reuqires a subscription.